# Is it a bad idea to upload image by POST JSON with DataURL?

Tags: html, forms, post, web, data-uri

What I mean is I convert the image to DataURL and make a JSON like

```
[{id: 1, dataurl: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,asdf***'}, {id: 2, dataurl: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,fsdfas***'}]
```

and post it to server.

Will it be different from uploading image by Form(multipart)?

Comment: The base64 conversion will make it larger, but other than that it'll _probably_ work.

Comment: But: _why_? This is such a strange thing to do.

Comment: For example, I will let user to select image and edit it, after that I only can get a DataURL of the modified image.

Comment: You could instead submit a representation of the edits the user performed, and have the server (in a PHP script or otherwise) perform the image manipulation and produce the final image. This would save you a bunch of resources.

Otherwise, there's no reason why your approach won't _work_, it's just unusual and uses a lot of bandwidth.

Comment: but server does not have the image before user upload it :) in common, user select image and send to server. I want user to select then edit then send.

Comment: I suppose you could upload the image first with a form, and then show it to the user for modification, and then do my suggestion. You're probably better off as you are.